# How can I group the numbers by 5?

Tags: python

```
def num ():

    num = int (input("Enter a number: ") )
    while num in range (num >= 0,100) :
        num += 1
        print (num, end = " ")
num ()
```

My problem is I don't know how to group it into 5 (for e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 and the next line is 6 7 8 9 10). 5 numbers each line. And when the user inputs a number, it will count up from that number inputted.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, can you explain what were you trying to achieve with the while loop? I've been coding in python for quite a while and have never seen a `range` used like this.

Comment: I'm just only experimenting with the for and while loop. Because the for loop to my code did not work. So I changed it to while and it works with range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
num = int (input("Enter a number: "))
i = 100
while num in range (num >= 1,100) :
    num += 1
    i += 1
    print (num, end = " ")
    if i%5 == 0:
        print()
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a number: 10

11 12 13 14 15       
16 17 18 19 20    
21 22 23 24 25
```

....

Comment: It works! Thankyou so much. I've been struggling this code since I'm new in python programming language.

Comment: thanks @karakfa for correcting me about that case now I managed it

Comment: Why does `i` starts at `100`? Why not `0`?

Comment: @Justin please change `(num >= 0,100)` to `(num >= 1,100)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation:

```
num = int (input("Enter a number: ") )
l = list(range(num,100))
for i in range(0, len(l),5):
    print(" ".join(map(str, l[i:i+5])))
```

We take sublists of size 5 (or less for the last one if necesarry) and use `join` to create a string with spaces.  Since join needs strings, i use `map`

Example:  (input 83)

```
83 84 85 86 87
88 89 90 91 92
93 94 95 96 97
98 99
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this. Note, this handles when user input is 0.

```py
def num ():

    num = int (input("Enter a number: "))
    count = 0
    if num == 0:
        foo = range(0, 100)
        for num in foo:
            count += 1
            print(num, end = " ")
            if count == 5:
                count = 0
                print()
    else:
        while num in range(num >= 0,100):
            num += 1
            count += 1
            print (num, end = " ")
            if count == 5:
                count = 0
                print()
num ()
```

```
Enter a number: 13
14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 
24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31 32 33 
34 35 36 37 38 
39 40 41 42 43 
44 45 46 47 48 
49 50 51 52 53 
54 55 56 57 58 
59 60 61 62 63 
64 65 66 67 68 
69 70 71 72 73 
74 75 76 77 78 
79 80 81 82 83 
84 85 86 87 88 
89 90 91 92 93 
94 95 96 97 98 
99 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import islice

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
get_sublist = lambda iterable,length: list(islice(iterable, length))
print(list(iter(partial(get_sublist, iter(range(num,100)), 5), [])))
```

```
Enter a number: 12
[[12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29, 30, 31],   
[32, 33, 34, 35, 36], [37, 38, 39, 40, 41], [42, 43, 44, 45, 46], [47, 48, 49, 50, 51],   
[52, 53, 54, 55, 56], [57, 58, 59, 60, 61], [62, 63, 64, 65, 66], [67, 68, 69, 70, 71],  
[72, 73, 74, 75, 76], [77, 78, 79, 80, 81], [82, 83, 84, 85, 86], [87, 88, 89, 90, 91],  
[92, 93, 94, 95, 96], [97, 98, 99]]
```

ref : `more_itertools`

Answer (score -3):

This may be able to be condensed but:

```
num = int (input("Enter a number: ") )
while i <= 100:
      print(i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5)
      i = i + 5
```

Comment: `i = 0` need to be initialize